# Hardware trigger sound card output

Tags: sound, hardware

I would like to trigger the output of a sound card such that the device starts playing at a precise moment in time.

Normally the sound card attached to your pc will start playing after it receives a software trigger from the operating system. When the user clicks play, there is some delay before the sound card starts its output. This delay is not the same every time, and it depends upon what the operating system is doing when the user attempts to start playback.

I would like to remove this irreproducible latency, such that the sound card will start at a known time, provided by a electronic trigger from an external device. (The external device would provide a TTL digital signal, and I would like to trigger on the rising or lowering edge.)

Does anyone know how to achieve this with any commercially available sound card?

Thanks, 
labjunky

Comment: Hi, and welcome to EEse. On this board asking for shopping advice is not allowed, and in my opinion your question is borderline. Provide some additional informations about your situation, there might be an easyier solution, eg you might work directly on the audio output if your sound is a pure tone, or maybe the whole thing you are trying to build has an easier way of being done.

Comment: 1. You're trying to reinvent MIDI. 2. PCs are deprecated for applications requiring precise timing such as you describe. Try a Mac.

Comment: Its not a questions of shopping, its a question of hacking a sound card to start playback at a given moment. (Does not have to be immediately.)

Comment: @user35648: Pc/mac is irrelevant to my question. But how can I use the midi to sync playback to a TTL signal?

Comment: @VladimirCravero: The nice thing about sound cards, as apposed to analog output cards, is that they can provide 24 bit signal quality for a relatively cheap price. For my application I need 24 bit signal quality, to generate a simple waveform, but at a known phase, that other signals an be synchronised to.

Comment: so you're asking how to build a signal generator starting from a sound card?

Answer (score 2):

You (probably) cannot do what you are trying to do.

Sound buffers have a certain amount of data in them.  Using the playback rate, we can measure this in time.  A common "real time" sound buffer duration would be, say, 5 ms.  Every 5 ms the CPU needs interrupted so it can generate the next 5 ms of data.

The problem you will run into is that the user presses play asynchronously to this hypothetical 5ms timer.  If you're really lucky, the user presses play just before the timer expires, and the sound begins to play "immediately".  If you're really unlucky, the user presses play just after the timer expires, and the sound will begin to play "5 ms after immediately".

Even if you knew exactly when the 5ms timer was going to fire, you can't make people press play synchronously with that timer.  You will always have a variable latency the size of 0 <= x <= sizeof(SoundBuffer)

Comment: I don't need the sound to play immediately. I just need it to play in sync with other devices. For example, if I were to play a simple sine wave of a certain tone, I would like it to start playback when an external TTl triggers it, then I will know after x seconds the exact phase of that tone, which is important for my application.

Comment: You do not "start" playback.  The host sound buffers are *always* pumping, even if there is nothing to play.  What starts is the mixing of a new sound into the current stream.  An external TTL trigger will suffer from the same asynchronous playback as a human clicking play; the external trigger has no idea where in the current buffer the sound card is *right now* and so its activation will fall anywhere between 0 <= x <= sizeof(SoundBuffer)

Comment: Is there anyway of finding out where in the buffer we are?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are talking about playing some sort of samples that are already stored on a sound card, anything that a sound card "plays" has to come from the driver associated with the sound card, and that driver in turn has to be fed by some software on the PC.

As you said, that process is started when the user clicks on the Play icon.  At that point the audio (the beginning of which may already be loaded into RAM as a result of the media file being "opened") is sent to the driver associated with the sound card.

Once that process is started, DMA may be used to feed the audio to the driver at a sufficient rate to play out the sound at a CD or higher rate, which is a non-trivial task -- CD quality sound, at 44.1 kHz, requires a stereo sample to be sent out every 22.7 µs, which if done strictly in software using a timer interrupt at that rate, would place a burden on the processor.

Assuming the computer is using DMA, then Windows only has to keep reading blocks into RAM fast enough so the driver never runs out of audio to play.

However there is a latency after you hit the Play button before the first samples are sent.

The sound card hardware has no way of making this happen any faster, since it doesn't have access to the system's file system.  So even if a hardware trigger was available as a GPIO (general purpose I/O) pin on the sound card, it would not be able to perform any actions locally on the sound card that would immediately start the audio to be played out, but instead would have to handled as an input to the sound card driver already mentioned, which would mimic the Play button being pressed somehow, and this would incur the same latency described above.

On the other hand, if you are talking about audio that can completely be pre-loaded into the sound card itself (if it has that feature), which is going to be limited in duration, then it might be possible to have the sound card initiate the playing of such samples on the receipt of a hardware trigger.  But I would think these would be limited to several hundred milliseconds, or a few seconds at most.  It would not be applicable to playing out a media file.